# Parsing json data in iphone application

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, json

I am parsing data from server in json to use in iphone app in following it takes any search text field and post it server then matches the text and returs data 
below is my iphone code

```
    NSString*searchText=searchTextField.text;

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"searchCode=%@",searchText];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/searchCatalog.php?"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    NSData* myData=[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *dataArr=[json_string JSONValue];

    for (int i=0; i<[dataArr count]; i++) {


        if (!dataArr || !dataArr.count){


            if(resultArray!=nil){
                resultArray=nil;
                resultArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            }




        }



        NSDictionary *dict=[dataArr objectAtIndex:i];

        ObjectData *theObject =[[ObjectData alloc] init];



        [theObject setCategory:[dict objectForKey:@"category"]];
        [theObject setSub_Category:[dict objectForKey:@"sub_Category"]];    
        [theObject setContent_Type:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Type"]];
        [theObject setContent_Title:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Title"]];
        [theObject setPublisher:[dict objectForKey:@"publisher"]];
        [theObject setContent_Description:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Description"]];
        [theObject setContent_ID:[dict objectForKey:@"content_ID"]];
        [theObject setContent_Source:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Source"]];





        [resultArray addObject:theObject];
        [theObject release];
        theObject=nil;



    NSLog(@"%@", json_string);
```

Here is the result of JSOn string

```
       ProductivoApp[2087:c203] -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x57b5a10 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}
```

My PHP code for url

```
     $flu=$_POST['searchCode'];


       $query =mysql_query("SELECT * From catalog_Master WHERE category_Title LIKE '%$flu%'");

    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
     }
```

Comment: Have u checked that the service URL in browser whether its returning response data properly?

Comment: why do you have a "?" at the end of your URL, in POST you don't need it. Hope this helps

Comment: @Ganapathy it is showing 
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/pah_brd_v1/productivo/searchCatalog.php on line 68
[]

Comment: So u have some problem in ur service itself.

Answer (score 0):

As per your latest comment, the reason for this is that your query is failing.

Firstly, you should not be using `mysql_*` functions. See the big red box [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Secondly, it looks like you may be leaving yourself open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should be [escaping your queries](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Thirdly, you should be performing error checking on your query. Something similar to:

```
if(!$query) {
   die('Query failed. ' . mysql_error()');
}
```

This should give you an idea as to why the query is failing.

You've also not posted the code for your [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), you should also be error checking this. Something similar to:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
if(!$link) {
   // Handle it
}
```